# Can slidify use a custom framework instead of slidifyLibraries version?

Tags: slidify

I want to use slidify with a locally modified version of the revealjs framework instead of the version that's included in the slidifyLibraries package.

I'm working in selfcontained mode, so slidify copies the framework to the local libraries/frameworks folder.

Is there an easy way to tell `slidify()` to copy files to libraries from a different source than the slidifyLibraries package (similarly to the way I can tell `author()` to use a custom scaffold?

I can accomplish this by manually copying my local version of the framework into libraries/frameworks, but it would be nice to have slidify do this for me when I run slidify().